# Unable to log into websites with Firefox, says the username or password is incorrect

Tags: firefox, passwords, login

I cannot log into my google account from Firefox. I put in my user name and password and it tells me

> The username or password you entered is incorrect.

I know the information is correct. I can log in with IE just not firefox. Also when I go to superuser.com it asks for the beta password again. I type the password and hit the button and it does not accept it. It just reloads the page.

I am able to log into other sites.

I have disabled all the add-ons, problem started in 3.0.12 I upgraded to 3.0.13 then to 3.5.2 I downloaded firefox and reinstalled.

OS: WinXP home on Acer Aspire one netbook.

Comment: What are your cookie settings in Firefox set to?

Comment: ... and whilst you're looking at cookie settings check that you are allowing any needed JavaScript sources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're able to log into other sites, but just can't seem to log into one in particular, check to see if you're blocking that site specifically.

> Tools > Options > Privacy

In the Cookies section, make sure that you've checked:

> Accept cookies from sites

Then click **Exceptions**

[image: cookies]

See if you already have an entry for a site, and if so, whether or not it's blocked. If it is, you can either remove it or just add it in again with `Allow`.

Then **close** the Cookies dialog box and **OK** the Options dialog.

You should now be able to log into the site(s) you were unable to previously.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say accept cookies was not checked. I don't know how it got unchecked because I didn't do it, and no once else uses the computer. I also thought that would affect all sites I logged into not just google and superuser. However the fact that Superuser.com was giving me the beta screen should have been a dead give away that it was a cookie problem. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Maybe the cookie settings were reset somehow.

Answer (score 4):

Either Firefox is not accepting cookies and/or is blocking JavaScript from Google/superuser.com.

Comment: +1 Your info was correct, however the accepted answer was more detailed. Thanks for your help